# Blender can't utilize all 24gb of VRAM (Out of memory)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, hardware, memory-management, compatibility

My system is 3090 Ti (24gb VRAM), 32gb DDR4, i7 8700k, Windows 10.

I've upgraded GPU recently because 8gb of VRAM on my old one wasn't enough, causing out of memory use or crashes in heavy scenes. However the new GPU acts similarly in heavy scenes, it crashes at around 14-15gb use of VRAM. It never uses all 24gb of VRAM.

The theory I've read online is that I need to have twice as much RAM as I have VRAM because of some Windows hard lock. So I need 48gb of RAM apparently? Could this be true and is there a way to unlock VRAM without upgrading? Task Manager shows I have 24gb of dedicated GPU memory, 16gb of shared GPU memory and 40gb of total memory. Why can't Blender use more than 16?

I render in Cycles: OptiX. My previous GPU 2070S 8gb was able to fully utilize all it's VRAM with scenes going up to 8200mb in VRAM use.

Comment: I would try updating GPU drivers and trying it with "Factory settings" (File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings, maybe backup your preferences first or be really careful not to save default preferences on top of yours, make sure that autosave preferences is off). Some addons may mess things up. Also if you are observing the VRAM usage using some other software, it might not be reporting it correctly. I would also try if not using the CPU as CUDA or OptiX device together with the GPU makes a difference.

Comment: I've already eliminated CPU from rendering devices. Latest GPU drivers and latest 3.4 Blender. Do you mean factory settings in Blender? I tried it just now. At 16656.20 mb it gave an error: "System is out of GPU and shared host memory". Task Manager showed about 17gb of dedicated GPU memory use at that moment.

Comment: Addons can have a huge impact it's worth trying without any addons loaded that's why I suggested Factory settings. Let's say new add-ons using Stable Diffusion... Anyway, so 17 out of 24... Might it be possible something else uses VRAM? Do you have Photoshop or some other software using GPU acceleration running, maybe software that might use AI? Task manager may show incorrect amount.

Comment: I have Chrome running. 3 displays connected. Those never stopped 2070S from utilizing all 8 gigs of VRAM.

Comment: I know nothing about GPU issues, but it might be worth checking if Linux has the same issue (you may need to install the latest NVidia drivers).

Comment: Might also be related to this where many users claim that Windows 10 swallows 20% of the VRAM (not se ure why you observe 50%?). It seems to be a limitation of the v2 of their driver, not existing on Windows 7 (so Linux might also not have this issue)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855185/how-can-i-use-100-of-vram-on-a-secondary-gpu-from-a-single-process-on-windows-1 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/15b9654e-5da7-45b7-93de-e8b63faef064/windows-10-does-not-let-cuda-applications-to-use-all-vram-on-especially-secondary-graphics-cards?forum=win10itprohardware

Comment: It swallows about 30% of dedicated VRAM. I'm about to replace RAM to get 64gb to test the theory that it helps, but would like some more confirmation if it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I bought 64 gigs of RAM and now Blender project uses all 24gb of VRAM. This issue should have been better advertised.

Comment: Can you confirm that was the problem? have you solved all the problems related to "Out Of Memory" I'm having the same problem with RTX 4090 24GB and 32GB Ram On the motherboard

Comment: You need 64 to utilize your GPU fully. It's unclear whether it's some Windows requirement or if Blender uses memory inefficiently though. But I can confirm that if a scene uses up to 20-24gb of VRAM the RAM usage jumps to 40-50s GB of RAM. RAM is necessary. After I upgraded I almost never run out of memory now.